# Ignore completion handler Swift

Tags: swift, closures

I have this function:

```
func getEvents(completion:@escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
    //here I do some async stuff 
    completion(asyncstuffresult)
}
```

In some cases, I want to wait for the result of this function, so I call it like this

```
getEvents { (success) in
    //whatever
}
```

However, sometimes I want to just fire the function, not really caring about how, or specifically when it is performed.

In that case, I would prefer to call it like this

```
getEvents()
```

for the sake of cleanliness

Is there a syntax that allows me to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can change your `func` to

```
func getEvents(completion: @escaping ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil)
```

as Apple does for

```
func dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil)
```

2. Another way is to set "empty" handler as default value to closure:

```
func getEvents(completion: @escaping ((Bool) -> Void) = { _ in })
```

All cases allow you to call func as `getEvents()` without closure parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `completion` to be an optional, like so:

```
func getEvents(completion:@escaping ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {
    //here I do some async stuff 
    completion?(asyncstuffresult)
}
```

Notice the optional `?` above in `completion?(asyncstuffresult)`, it executes the `completion` only if given. And you will be able to achieve a desired usage (without *necessarily* having to pass a `completion` handler)

```
getEvents()
```